# How to remove macOS sharing extensions from the shell?

Tags: terminal

In macOS 10.14.x, I'm having trouble with some sharing Extensions (System Preferences -> Extensions) causing some kind of hang. Unfortunately it's so bad that even the preference pane has become unresponsive.

I'd like to be able to remove these via the Terminal (shell) or by `ssh`'ing into the machine when things are particularly bad and that's the only way of accessing it.

Where are the folders that these extensions are stored so that I can disable them (probably by moving their files / bundles to a temporary `disabled` folder)?

Comment: It most likely a `launchd` agnet or daemon that's running.  For example, use the command `launchctl list | grep -i <name>` to see if there is a user agent for the service in question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not seeing them in there @Allan.

Comment: Try it with `sudo` as well - it may be something that was installed/run as an admin.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately no joy.

Comment: Look at your login items - under your user account.  Also, try booting in Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting).  Then try creating another user and see if the problem persists in that account as well (not in Safe Mode)